# Detecting Android InputMethod() API from web app

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, android-input-method

I am building a web app that will run on an Android device. This device has other software that creates text input via the Android InputMethod() API. If an input field on my web app has focus, then this text is correctly inserted into the input field. The problem is that if this InputMethod text event happens when an input field in the web app doesn't have focus, then the text is lost. I need to be able to always read text via the Android InputMethod() API, but it doesn't generate any keydown/keyup/keypress events so I'm a bit stumped at if this would even be possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to this is that you're probably not going to be able to do this via a web app, and you'll need to write an actual native app.  But here's an explanation of what goes on.

The InputMethod communicates via the InputConnection.  When a view receives focus, getInputConnection() is called on the view.  If that returns non-null, the view is saying it has the ability to accept input data, and the input connection will be connected to the IME (the keyboard) and data/requests will be sent via the InputConnection.  So data is ONLY send from the keyboard when its bound via a View.

You can grab input data by focusing a view, overriding the getInputConnection() function, and listening to the various calls on it (particularly commitText()).  But in a web app the only view you have is the WebView itself.  And overriding its getInputConnection function will probably break normal web text views.  So I wouldn't expect this to work.

Of course it generally isn't a problem because generally a soft keyboard isn't showing unless a text field is focused so you don't actually get this problem, although you could force the keyboard up in a few ways.

Comment: This makes me sad, but thank you so much for the detailed explanation on why this doesn't work!